# anchor tag font size not applying inside divtag from codebehind c#

Tags: asp.net, css

here am getting font size,family,backbolor from database.
so that value am applyng to anchortags inside div tag.
except font size remaining working fine.
here is my code.
here am tryied two types .
1. applying font size to div tag.
2.applying font size to ul tags

```
 <div id="sidenav" class="column" runat="server">
    <table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10">
    <tr>
    <td>        
            <ul id="abcd" runat="server">
                <li><a href="ViewEvents.aspx">Events</a></li>
                <li><a href="PhotoGalleries.aspx">Photo Galleries</a></li>
                <li><a href="InProgress.aspx">Location</a></li>
                <li><a href="InProgress.aspx">Officials</a></li>
                <li><a href="InProgress.aspx">Honours Board</a></li>
                <li><a href="InProgress.aspx">History</a></li>
                <li><a href="InProgress.aspx">Links</a></li>
                <li><a href="InProgress.aspx">Site map</a></li>
                <li><a href="InProgress.aspx">Help</a></li>
            </ul>
            </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
        </div>
panelLinks.Style.Add("background-color", objpage.MenuBackcolor);
            panelLinks.Style.Add("color", objpage.MenuTextcolor);
            panelLinks.Style.Add("font-family", objpage.MenuTextStyle);
            //contanerwrapper.Style.Add("font-size", objpage.BodyTextSize);
            //contanerwrapper.Style.Add("color", objpage.BodyTextBackcolor);
            //contanerwrapper.Style.Add("font-family", objpage.BodyTextStyle);
            abcd.Style.Add("background-color", objpage.NavigationBackcolor);
            abcd.Style.Add("color", objpage.NavigatioinTextcolor);
            abcd.Style.Add("font-family", objpage.NavigatioinTextStyle);
            abcd.Style.Add("font-size", objpage.NavigatioinTextsize);
 panelLinks.Style.Add("background-color", objpage.MenuBackcolor);
            panelLinks.Style.Add("color", objpage.MenuTextcolor);
            panelLinks.Style.Add("font-family", objpage.MenuTextStyle);
            //contanerwrapper.Style.Add("font-size", objpage.BodyTextSize);
            //contanerwrapper.Style.Add("color", objpage.BodyTextBackcolor);
            //contanerwrapper.Style.Add("font-family", objpage.BodyTextStyle);
            sidenav.Style.Add("background-color", objpage.NavigationBackcolor);
            sidenav.Style.Add("color", objpage.NavigatioinTextcolor);
            sidenav.Style.Add("font-family", objpage.NavigatioinTextStyle);
            sidenav.Style.Add("font-size", objpage.NavigatioinTextsize);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add code like

```
 abcd.Style.Add("font-size", string.Format(objpage.NavigatioinTextsize+"px")) ;
```

You should need to specify the [unit of measurement](http://kyleschaeffer.com/user-experience/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/) for font-size.